# Scrapy Spider only generates one item per loop

Tags: python, generator, scrapy

Since I added another request at the end of the for loop, to test a link, the Spyder only generates Items for the first index of the loop.

```
def parse_product_page(self, response):
    products = response.xpath('//div[@class="content"]//div[@class="tov-rows"]//div[@class="t-row"]')
    for x, product in enumerate(products):  #ERROR: Just gives an item for the first product
        product_loader = VerbraucherweltProdukt()
        product_loader['name'] = product.xpath(
            '//div[@class="t-center"]//div[@class="t-name"]/text()').extract_first()
        request = scrapy.Request(non_ref_link,callback=self.test_link, errback=self.test_link)
        request.meta['item'] = product_loader
        yield request
```

It all worked before when i just yielded the product item, but since the item is returned in the callback, i dont know where my problem lays.

The callback is just:

```
def test_link(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['link_fehlerhaft'] = response.status
    yield item
```

Also the full code, maybe the problem is anywhere else:
http://pastebin.com/tgL38zpD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your culprit:

```
link = product.xpath('//div[@class="t-right"]//a/@href').extract_first()
```

You're not grounding your recursive xpath to the product node you have. To fix it simply pre append `.` to your xpath to indicate current node as root:

```
link = product.xpath('.//div[@class="t-right"]//a/@href').extract_first()
```

Comment: Holy shit, would have overseen that so hard. Thank you so much. I only looked at the loop and the callback.

Comment: @JoshuaMenke no problem, this issue is probably the most common xpath related issues on stackoverflow. A huge throw off is that css selectors are immune to this issue so if you primarily use them you will be caught off guard